# Custom WP theme ignoring post and page content formating

Tags: php, wordpress, post, formatting, themes

I made a custom WordPress theme from scratch.

I am having an issue: when I post something on a page or post and use the Gutenberg editor to make something as simple as 2 columns with text and image (see images), the content on the page just puts them under each other and ignores the WP styling.

Screenshots:
content in the Gutenberg editor:
[image: Gutenberg editor side]

content on the page side:
[image: content on the page side]

Inspect Element side of the content:
[image]

I can also see the element that has the "wp-column-block" styling on it has no styling reaching it (as if there is no style.css for it so so!?):

[image: the styling of the element is missing]

I am using `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>` to fetch the content of the page which is in my singular.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<?php include 'parts/head.php'; ?>
<body>
    <!-- <?php wp_body_open();?> -->
    <?php
        $thumbnail_Link = get_template_directory_uri()."/media/home-hero-bk.jpeg";
        $thumbnaul_alt = "page thumbnail image";
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            $thumbnail_Link= get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
            $thumbnaul_alt = get_the_post_thumbnail_caption();
        }
    ?>
    <header class="page-hero" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumbnail_Link ?>');">
        <?php $dark_nav = false; include 'parts/nav.php'; ?>
    </header>
    <main class="page limit-page-width">
        <h2 class="page__title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        <section class="page-post">
            <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
            <?php if( get_field('page_shortcode') ): ?>
                <?php echo do_shortcode( get_field('page_shortcode') ) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
    </main>
    <?php include 'parts/footer.php'; ?>
</body>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script.js' ?>"></script>
</html>
```

and the following are the settings in my function.php:

```
<?php
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), null, true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
add_theme_support('title-tag');

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');

// Remove p tags from category description
remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');

function register_my_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
        'main-menu' => 'Main Menu',
        'footer-right' => 'Footer Right',
        'footer-left' => 'Footer Left'
        )
    );
}
add_action('init','register_my_menus');

function get_id_by_slug($page_slug) {
    $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
    if ($page) {
        return $page->ID;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
} 

$role = get_role('editor'); 
$role->add_cap('edit_theme_options');

function filter_content_example($content) {
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_content_example');

function new_excerpt_more($output) {
    return $output . '<p class="section-abposts__post__content__text"><a href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . 'Mehr lesen...' . '</a></p>';
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

How can I fix the issue so the client can just use the WordPress editor to format his posts?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to enable block styles support on your theme, see [Default block styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-support/#default-block-styles).

Comment: So I added it to my functions.php, but sadly I don't see any change.